# How to parameterize the source in Adf pipeline copy activity

Tags: azure, dynamic, pipeline, azure-data-factory, parametrize

I am new to Azure, so I have an SFTP server which has dev,qa and prod data, the user is same but the data is placed in separate folders, can anyone please tell me how to copy the files dynamically, that is I want to fetch the files from the dev folder in the dev environment and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parameter in the source dataset and pass the folder name dynamically.

1. Create a folder name parameter in the source dataset.

[image]

2. Create a pipeline parameter and pass the value to dataset properties in copy data activity in run time.

[image]

Copy data activity:

[image]